# Have I shown that this function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$C([0,1])$ is the set of continuous functions $u:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}.$ For any $u\in C([0,1])$ let $\displaystyle Lu(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 e^{-u(x)}(x+t)\,dx.$
I'm to show that $L$ defines a mapping $L:C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$.

I want to show that for any $u\in C([0,1]),\; (Lu)$ is continuous.

\begin{align*}
|Lu(t)-Lu(t')| &= \left|\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1e^{-u(x)}(x+t)\,dx -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1e^{-u(x)}(x+t')\,dx \,\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1e^{-u(x)}(t-t')\,dx\,\right|\\
&\leq \frac12 \, |t-t'| \cdot 2M \leq |t-t'|,
\end{align*} where $M = 1$ is an upper bound on
$e^{-u(x)}$.

Have I now shown that $L$ is (Lipschitz) continuous?

Comment: I’m no expert but it looks like you just showed that any function given by  L(u)(t) is Lipschitz in t. This is kind of obvious since L maps to a space of continuous functions. If you want to show continuity of the transform L, you need to consider the norm of the difference between L(u) and L(u’), where u’ is a totally different function in C[0, 1] and compare it to the norm of the difference between u and u’. You need to work in function space, not “t space”. What’s a good norm on a function in C[0, 1]?

Comment: I guess you did do something useful because you showed that any function L(u) is continuous, which it looks like you were required to show. Sorry if that was a bit unclear on my part. However you do have to go further and show that L is a continuous mapping between function spaces, and for that you will have to work out what it means for functions to be “close together”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is $M=1$ an upper bound for $e^{-u}$ ??

With your proof we get:

$|Lu(t)-Lu(t')| \le \frac{1}{2}||e^{-u}||_{\infty}|t-t'|$.

Comment: Because $e^{-x}\leq 1$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$?

Comment: If $u(x)=-34$ for some $x \in [0,1]$, then $e^{-u(x)}=e^{34}>1$ !

Comment: Yeah, then I was wrong and I don't know how to proceed =/

Comment: Proceed ? You are done. $Lu$ is Lipschitz- continuous

Comment: @Mathaniel: $x \mapsto e^{-u(x)}$ is bounded since it is continuous on $[0,1]$. Let M as it is and your proof is correct.

Comment: Lol, shows how much I know about real analysis. Even when I'm correct I can't recognize it :P

Comment: @Fred why do you get $|Lu(t)-Lu(t')| \leq \frac{1}{2}||e^{-u}||_{\infty}|t-t'|$? Why the infinity norm?